# Sort the data linked by a relationship by date

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-blade, laravel-9

I'm having a problem sorting projects based on the date of the last task associated with it. I explain better.

I have a relationship between project and tasks **One to Many** (as a project can have one or more tasks). In the project table, for each project, I have a column where I print the date of the last task done, as you can see in the blade view shown below. So far everything ok.

Now the projects are sorted by default in ascending order of creation of each project (so the last project shown in the table is the one that is added last).

What I want is to sort the projects by the date obtained from the last task associated with that project through the column corresponding to the date of the last task I get as shown below.

Model Project:

```
class Project extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'name',
    ];

    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $projects = Project::withCount('tasks')->get();
        return view('project.index', compact('projects'));
    }
```

View:

```
 <table id="tabledata">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Date last task</th>
                    <th>N. Tasks</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach ($projects as $project)
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="p-4">{{ $project->title}}</a></td>
                    <td class="p-4">{{ $project->name }}</a></td>
                    <td class="p-4">{{ $project->tasks()->latest()->first()->created_at->format('d/m/Y') }}</td>
                    <td class="text-center">{{ $project->tasks_count}}</td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

To sort your query by the data of relationship column, you can change your query to something like this:

```
$projects = Project::with('tasks')->orderByDesc(Task::select('created_at')->whereColumn('tasks.project_id', 'project.id')->latest()->take(1))->withCount('tasks')->get();
```

***orderBy()*** and ***orderByDesc()*** query builder methods support passing a query, instead of just a column name.

What we did here is:

1. We took the tasks of the project
2. We passed in a query as a subquery to the ***orderByDesc*** query builder method.
3. Inside the subquery:

   - We selected the **created_at** column from the tasks table.
   - We limited the results by comparing the **project_id** column of tasks table to the **id** column of the projects table.
   - Then we call the **latest()** method, which sorts the tasks to the recent record first.
   - And lastly, we limit the results to only one row, since a subquery can only return a single row and column

You can read more about how it works with different types of relationships [here](https://reinink.ca/articles/ordering-database-queries-by-relationship-columns-in-laravel)

Comment: It does not work. With your query I get the projects sorted by id and not sorted by the last task created for each of them